# Javascript asynchronous event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

On user event async ajax call not working asynchronously.
Issue may be due session.
found one solution session_write_close

But how to integrate this with codeingiter.
[jquery ajax call not asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087097/jquery-ajax-call-not-asynchronous)

button1 click action1()  30seconds
button2 click action2()   5seconds

If I click on button1 first then button2 . I want action2() should not wait to finish execution of action1().

Below is sample code

```
function action1(){
        $.ajax({
                url: '/action1',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                data: $( 'form[name=form1]' ).serialize(),
                success : function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                   },
        });
}

function action2(){
        $.ajax({
                url: '/action2',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                data: $( 'form[name=form2]' ).serialize(),
                success : function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                   },
        });
}
```

Comment: AJAX calls are Asynchronous by default, meaning the calls are fired and rest of the code continues its execution. Your button 2 click should work just fine. Why should it wait for first AJAX call at all?

Comment: are you sure that the action2 is waiting for action1 to get completed?. I dont think so

Comment: Yes, onload this works fine. on user event works synchronously.

Comment: Maybe your server running in one thread?

Comment: log `beforesend` event, I'm sure you will see it fire.

Comment: it is due to session, how to stop session for these action.

Answer (score 2):

It works async as expected. You can check it in chrome or firefox console in network tab.
The reason of slow response can be on the server side of your app.

Comment: I observed it is due to session and solution added in question. but not getting where to call session_write_close(); in action . If I call it in constructor then not able to save any session data.